# How to check for a valid user input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build the Bulls & Cows game in C++.  I've implemented most of the logic.  The game runs continuously with the use of an infinite loop and generates a random value at each run.

What I'm trying to do now is to now is to take the user input and run the code if the input is valid (can ONLY be a 4 digit integer).  This is my implementation:

```
#include ...

using namespace std;

vector<int> getDigits(int modelValue) {
    vector<int> vectorValue;
    int extractedDigit = 0;
    int modulant = 10000;
    int divisor = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        extractedDigit = (modelValue % modulant) / divisor;
        vectorValue.push_back(extractedDigit);
        modulant /= 10;
        divisor /= 10;
    }return vectorValue;
}


int main() {
    for (;;) {
        int model = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
        int guess = 0000;
        int bulls = 0;
        int cows = 0;
        int counter = 1;

        cout << "This is the random 4-digit integer: " << model << endl;
        cout << "Enter a value to guess: ";
        cin >> guess;

        if ((guess >= 1000) && (guess <= 9999) && (cin)) {

            vector<int> modelVector = getDigits(model);
            vector<int> guessVector = getDigits(guess);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                if (find(modelVector.begin(), modelVector.end(), guessVector[i]) != modelVector.end()) {
                    if (modelVector[i] == guessVector[i]) { bulls += 1; }
                    else { cows += 1; }
                }
            }cout << "There are " << bulls << " bulls and " << cows << " cows" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Please enter a valid 4-digit integer between 0000 and 9999" << endl;
            cin.clear();
        }
    }return 0;
}
```

But when I run and input something invalid, what I get is a continuously running [image: console].

Comment: You aren't breaking out of the loop anywhere...

Comment: Can you clarify "continuously running console"?  Is it at least showing the error message and asking for more input, or is it just hanging?  What inputs have you tried?

Comment: @LukeRamsden what I want to do is to `cout` an error message incase of a weird input and start over.  @Brandon McKenzie.  The console just runs continously.  Its basically "hanging" if you will.

Comment: I have just posted an answer for the very same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374003/3545273) (cannot mark it as a duplicate until other answer is accepted or upvoted)

Comment: @SergeBallesta why don't you post that answer relevant to this question and delete that one so I can accept your answer?

Comment: @OnurOzbek: Nice proposal, but I am too lazy for it :-)

Comment: Also @SergeBallesta a 2nd look shows a difference.  I already have a `cin` check in my code.  Previously I tried `cin.fail()`.  It made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you read the user input, it just doesn't check for the input type before assigning the value into your 'guess' variable.

So, if an user put any value that isn't accepted by the integer type it would crash your application generating this infinite loop.

To protect your integer variable from wrong user inputs you must replace your direct input assignment:

```
cin >> guess;
```

By a protected one:

```
while(!(cin >> guess) || (guess < 1000)){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Invalid input. Please, try again: ";
}
```

Into the *while* above you can see the "numeric_limits::max()" which is explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max):

> Returns the maximum finite value representable by the numeric type T. Meaningful for all bounded types.

At the end you have a *while* holding the user into this reading loop while its input is under 1000 (as requested) or isn't a valid integer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`

Comment: Elaborate on all of it. Code dumps aren't answers.

Comment: @OnurOzbek please, check if the answer is more appropriate now. Thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're missing some magic words in your sentence. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @AntonioAlecrimJr: Nope, nothing is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `cin.ignore()`.  It'll help you flush the `cin` buffer.

Comment: But that's not the problem.

Comment: Well, yes it is. If someone enters something that cannot be extracted into an `int`, that something doesn't go away, and you still won't be able to extract it into an `int` on the next loop iteration either. It's still in the buffer, waiting for you to extract it into something compatible. You need to skip over it, to remove it from the input buffer. This has been covered many, many times on Stack Overflow, and should also be explained in your C++ book.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit he changed his answer.  Initially he asked me to switch to a while loop, when that wasn't what I was asking.

Comment: @OnurOzbek: Ah yes, I see that now. Okay!