# Input data type check in loop not working as intended (C++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to get user input and then check if the input is an integer and then return it. If I enter an integer then it will return the value but if the input is a string then it will endlessly output `>>>Failed`

I was using [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18728865/4180176) as the base.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int getRandomNumber(int maxNum) {
    return rand() % maxNum + 1;
}

int getIntInput() {
    int input;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << ">>> ";
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << std::flush;

        if (std::cin.fail() || input < 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed";
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    return input;
}


int main() {
    int numGuessed;
    int randomNum = getRandomNumber(100);

    numGuessed = getIntInput();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you only clear the error condition but never *flush* the offending input, so the input stream stays at the erroneous characters. The common way is to read (and discard) a full line for a failed conversion:

```
while (true) {
    std::cout << ">>> ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << std::flush;

    if (std::cin.eof()) {    // do not try to read past an eof!
        input = 0;
        break;
    }
    if (std::cin.fail() || input < 0) {
        std::string line;
        std::cin.clear();              // reset the fail flag
        std::getline(std::cin, line);  // read until end of line
        std::cout << "Failed";
        continue;
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: I get an error ```'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::getline': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments``` Any fix?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: I made a confusion between different `getline` functions. Fixed now.

Comment: std has no member getline, so it says :P FIXED: needed to add the string header